# Any way to run python TK scripts on web page?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to run a python script that utilizes TKinter on a web page such that a user could run the script and interact with the TK windows without having to download the script or have the appropriate python interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The only approach I can think of, is to use some virtual screen protocol such as VNC, run your Tkinter script on a server for that protocol (e.g., a VNC server), and use a viewer browser plug-in for that protocol in the user's browser (e.g., maybe [this one](http://www.s-code.com/products/viewerx/webvnc.aspx) -- haven't tried it myself, though).  A similar approach could use the NX protocol (e.g., cfr [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX)).

Note that such solutions will most likely not scale well: they're mostly meant to let **one** user connect to "their desktop" from a browser.  Performance, robustness and scalability of web-native approaches will all run rapid circles around any such "compatibility hack"!